# sbt-cloudbees-play-plugin deploy gets NullPointerException on BrowserLauncher

Tags: playframework-2.1, cloudbees

When I deploy using cloudbees-deploy-config, I got a Null Pointer exception on BrowserLauncher. I followed the instruction on sbt-cloudbees-play-plugin to set it up. Did I miss anything?

```
[info] Deploying myapp-1.0.3[config=application-prod] to Run@Cloud/myapp/a
........................uploaded 25%
........................uploaded 50%
........................uploaded 75%
........................upload completed
deploying application to server(s)...
[info] Application available at http://a.myapp.cloudbees.net
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at cloudbees.Plugin$.cloudbees$Plugin$$performDeploy(cloudbees.scala:236)
    at cloudbees.Plugin$$anonfun$deployConfigTask$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(cloudbees.scala:150)
    at cloudbees.Plugin$$anonfun$deployConfigTask$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(cloudbees.scala:113)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf6$1.apply(Structure.scala:582)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf6$1.apply(Structure.scala:582)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.stanford.ejalbert.launching.BrowserLaunchingFactory.createSystemBrowserLaunching(BrowserLaunchingFactory.java:62)
    at edu.stanford.ejalbert.BrowserLauncher.initBrowserLauncher(BrowserLauncher.java:248)
    at edu.stanford.ejalbert.BrowserLauncher.<init>(BrowserLauncher.java:226)
    at edu.stanford.ejalbert.BrowserLauncher.<init>(BrowserLauncher.java:162)
    at cloudbees.BrowserLauncher$.<init>(cloudbees.scala:13)
    at cloudbees.BrowserLauncher$.<clinit>(cloudbees.scala)
    at cloudbees.Plugin$.cloudbees$Plugin$$performDeploy(cloudbees.scala:236)
    at cloudbees.Plugin$$anonfun$deployConfigTask$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(cloudbees.scala:150)
    at cloudbees.Plugin$$anonfun$deployConfigTask$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(cloudbees.scala:113)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf6$1.apply(Structure.scala:582)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf6$1.apply(Structure.scala:582)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[error] (*:cloudbees-deploy-config) java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error] Total time: 131 s, completed Aug 15, 2013 11:46:14 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see you already created an issue for this https://github.com/CloudBees-community/sbt-cloudbees-play-plugin/issues/5
I expect plugin contributors to reply there

Comment: I haven't heard anything from contributors.